# Changing name of properties file leads to it not being found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a properties file called **application.properties**:

```
mysql.connectionUrl=jdbc:somesql://index.mycust.cr:0000/dbName
mysql.username=me
mysql.password=mypass
```

This is used by my class **DbNameConnectionProperties.java** like this:

```
package com.mycom.mycust.somesql.dbconnection;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties("mysql")
public class DbNameConnectionProperties {

    private String connectionUrl;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getConnectionUrl() {
        return connectionUrl;
    }

    public void setConnectionUrl(String connectionUrl) {
        this.connectionUrl = connectionUrl;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

This runs fine. Now I want to change the name of the **application.properties** file (I will need another file with properties in it for another database). So I simply change the file name of **application.properties** to **something.properties**, as well as the name in the `@PropertySource` annotation:

**something.properties**:

```
mysql.connectionUrl=jdbc:somesql://index.mycust.cr:0000/dbName
mysql.username=me
mysql.password=mypass
```

**DbNameConnectionProperties.java**:

```
package com.mycom.mycust.somesql.dbconnection;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:something.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties("mysql")
public class DbNameConnectionProperties {

    // same as before
}
```

This crashes:

```
2019-06-17 16:34:20,593 [ ERROR ] o.s.b.SpringApplication:842 : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.findwise.svenskaakademin.processing.Processing]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [something.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at com.findwise.svenskaakademin.processing.Processing.main(Processing.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [something.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:159)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:99)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:73)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:59)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:67)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(DefaultPropertySourceFactory.java:37)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:453)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170)
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `something.properties` is not on the classpath. Double check it is created in resources directory.

Comment: How do I double check this (what is resources directory?)?

Comment: Usually it is `resources` directory :)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. You're right, it's not there, only `application.properties` is there.

Comment: Why isn't it there? What do I need to do to either get it there or refer to it in another way?

Comment: I don;t know where you put it. If you would place it next to application.properties, it should work right away. Maybe you places it in sources not resources so it will be filtered out on packaging.

Comment: Previously, I simply put the application.properties in `root/config`. I never put it in `root/somesql-parent/object-mapper/src/main/resources/`. Also, the properties in `resources/` are different from the ones in `config/`. I simply changed the name of `root/config/application.properties` and then got the error.

Comment: Also, changing the name of `root/somesql-parent/object-mapper/src/main/resources/application.properties` to something.properties does not fix the error.

Comment: Whatever it is, its impossible to say. Diagnosis is correct - cause you have to find yourself as I am not in your shoes nor I see project structure.